# Obtaining inequality between two variables

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, replacement, algebraic-manipulation

I have two variables

```
t[a_, b_,c_] := (Sqrt[3 + 2 (Cos[a] + Cos[b] + Cos[c])] + 
                Sqrt[3 + 2 (Cos[a] - Cos[b] - Cos[c])] + 
                Sqrt[3 + 2 (-Cos[a] - Cos[b] + Cos[c])] + 
                Sqrt[3 + 2 (-Cos[a] + Cos[b] - Cos[c])])/2; 

p[a_, b_, c_] := 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[3 + 2 (Cos[a] + Cos[b] + Cos[c])]/3);
```

I need to upper bound `p` with some expression of `t`. Is there any way for me to solve this analytically inside mathematica?

Plotting `p` against `t`, with some constraints on `a`, `b`, and `c` yields,

```
 (*Initalizing*)
 n = 1;
 g={};
 (*Angles are between 0 and Pi/2*)
 ang = Pi/2; 
 While[n < 10000, a = RandomReal[{0, ang}]; 
       b = RandomReal[{0, ang}]; 
       Label[begin];  
       c = RandomReal[{0, ang}]; 
       (*Additional constraint on c*)
       If[c \[Element] Interval[{Abs[a - b], a + b}],
         Goto[end],
         Goto[begin]]; 
       Label[end]; pra = p[a, b, c]; tra = t[a, b, c];
       AppendTo[g, {tra,pra}]; n++]; 
 ListPlot[g]
```

[image: t vs p]

The relevant range of the x-axis (`t`) is from 3 to 3.46. In that range, the plot is bounded by a curve. I want to express an upper bound for `p` (y-axis) in terms of `t` which should trace out that curve.

Comment: Can you elaborate "
I need to upper bound `p` with some expression of `t`"? I  understand neither it nor the result of your code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I need to analytically derive an upper bound for `p` depending only on `t`. The curve in the result shows what such an upperbound should look like.

Comment: Still don't understand. What role do `a,b,c` play?

Comment: `p` and `t` are functions of `a`, `b` , and `c`

Comment: I am waiting for a reach-in-content reply. BTW, I am PhD in math for ages.

Comment: I presume that you are seeking s symbolic expression for the upper edge of the dots in your plot.  Is that correct?

Comment: @bbgodfrey yes that is true

Comment: @user64494 My objective is to have a function of `t` which is an upper bound of `p`. I couldn't solve it directly so I thought I could gain some insights from plotting the functions and obtaining the equation of the curve from it.

Comment: @Dotman: You don't specify the ranges of `a,b,c` and the relations between them in your question. This is not a good practice. Regard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, your code is not working properly because `c \[Element] Interval[{Abs[a - b], a + b}]` remains unevaluated and this additional constraint is not obeyed. To check whether a number lies in the interval, you should use function `IntervalMemberQ` (or present the number as a "point" by wrapping it a list: `{c} \[Element] Interval[...]`).

Secondly, your code style is very procedural so I made some changes to make it more *Mathematica*-like.

```
Clear[a, b, c];

ang = Pi/2;
g = Module[{a, b, c}, Table[
   a = RandomReal[{0, ang}]; 
   b = RandomReal[{0, ang}]; 
   c = RandomReal[
     Last@IntervalIntersection[Interval[{0, ang}], 
       Interval[{Abs[a - b], a + b}]]];
   {t[a, b, c], p[a, b, c]}, 10000]];
ListPlot[g]
```

This now gives the correct plot.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now to your question. Let's say we don't want to go through the tedious algebra and want to get some insight just by looking at the problem. Let's see which points $(a,b,c)$ get mapped to the boundary. The boundary can be created by the convex hull.

```
pts = Module[{a, b, c}, Table[
   a = RandomReal[{0, ang}]; b = RandomReal[{0, ang}]; 
   c = RandomReal[
     Last@IntervalIntersection[Interval[{0, ang}], 
       Interval[{Abs[a - b], a + b}]]];
   {{a, b, c}, {t[a, b, c], p[a, b, c]}}, 10000]];

abc = pts[[All, 1]];
xy = pts[[All, 2]];
hull = ConvexHullRegion[pts[[All, 2]]][[1]];

Row[{
  ListPlot[hull, ImageSize -> 400],
  ListPointPlot3D[abc[[First@Position[xy, #] & /@ hull // Flatten]], 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> 400, 
   AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "c"}]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Wonderful! It seems like points $(a,a,a)$ are the ones that get mapped
to the upper boundary.

```
Show[ListPlot[xy], 
 ParametricPlot[{t[a, a, a], p[a, a, a]}, {a, 0, \[Pi]/2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now let's get the explicit formula:

```
Solve[x == t[a, a, a] && y == p[a, a, a], {y, a}, Reals]
```

Because of inverse functions, we get two different solutions for $y$, and the corresponding range is $3\leq x \leq 2\sqrt3$. By manual inspection, we can choose the correct one.

$$y(x) = \frac{1}{12} \left(\sqrt{2 x \left(\sqrt{36-3
   x^2}-x\right)+36}+6\right)$$

Let's verify it again to be sure:

```
Show[ListPlot[xy], 
 Plot[1/12 (6 + Sqrt[36 + 2 x (-x + Sqrt[36 - 3 x^2])]), {x, 3, 
   2 Sqrt[3]}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for the correction. But why doesnt the `If` statement work? This is my first time using `Goto` command.

Comment: The problem is not in using ``If`` or ``Goto`` but in using ``\[Element]``. Mathematica just dosn't understand this syntax (i.e. ``x \[Element] Interval[...]``), and leaves the if-statement unevaluated. I have now updated my answer to provide the full solution. Let me know if any of the steps are incomprehensible or need additional explanation.

Comment: Just saw the edit. It's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. Also, what's the right way to use `\[Element]`?

Comment: You can use [``\[Element]``](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html) with _domains_ (such as ``Reals``, ``Integers``, ``Rationals`` ...) or with _regions_ (such as ``Sphere``, ``Ball``, ``MeshRegion`` ...). You _can_ also use it with _intervals_ (which are actually some kind of regions), but you have to write the number as a "point", i.e. wrap it into a list: ``{1} \[Element] Interval[{0, 2}]``.

Answer (score 2):

To get a curve through the uppermost points we first select the points in the range 3 to 3.46 (this eliminates imaginary points and gets rid of superfluous points):

```
dat = Select[g, (# \[Element] Reals && 3 <= #[[1]] <= 3.46) &];
```

Now we are only interested in the top most points. To get these, we sort in reverse and then scan the data and make the data monotonically increasing:

```
t = 0;
dat = {#[[1]], t = Max[t, #[[2]]]} & /@ dat
```

Now the data looks like:

```
ListLinePlot[dat]
```

[image]

To get a smooth function, we fit a polynomial to these points:

```
n = 5;
base = Table[x^i, {i, 0, n}];
poly = Fit[dat, base, x]
(*8295.17 - 13077.3 x + 8246.08 x^2 - 2599.41 x^3 + 409.645 x^4 - 
 25.82 x^5*)

Plot[poly, {x, 3, 3.46}, Epilog -> {PointSize[0.001],Point[dat]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{3, 3.46}, {0.8, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]